# Can anyone show me the process to get the result Undefined (1/0) from Tangent inverse one (-2/0) [ tan−1(-2/0) ]?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

I know that $\tan^{-1}(1/0)$ is undefined. But I'm getting a little trouble figuring out this $\tan^{−1}(-2/0)$. The answer of $\tan^{−1}(-2/0)$ will also be Undefined.
By the way, I got the problem while solving some complex numbers and finding their argument. The complex number was $0-2i$.
Thanks in advance.
Asif Touhid.

Comment: Dividing by zero -> Undefined

Comment: @Asif Touhid Do you have problem on the phase of this complex number?

Comment: Yes, but can you please compare this (2/0) with (1/0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we think about a generic complex number as $z=a+ib$ then it is possible to observe that:
$a+ib=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ (Argand-Gauss representation), where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

In our case we have $\displaystyle a=0$ (and $b=-2$),  and so from the equality above $r\cos\theta=0\implies \theta=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\implies \sin{\theta}=\pm1$.

In our case we have to look at the negative case since $b<0$ and $r>0$, so: $\displaystyle \sin\theta=-1\iff  \theta=-\frac\pi2$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Would you please compare arctan(2/0) with arctan(1/0) please?

Comment: Nothing changes in terms of phase what's change is the modulus and so $r$ (it is 2 or 1 in the second case)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time!